# Host for Mongo db atlas: only work locally not on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I am newbie in programming restful api with nodejs and mongo db atlas.

I finished all the videos in this list https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucuNgSOFDZ0&index=14&list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q

I can run my code successful locally at localhost:3000 but when I deploy it on heroku, It crashes then I try with "heroku logs" and it shows that: [image]
[image]
[image]

You can find the whole project at: https://github.com/academind/node-restful-api-tutorial/tree/13-controllers (just neet to change the password field for mongo atlas in the nodemon.json)

Please help. Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Error Message says: "Invalid ELF Header". This has nothing to do with MongoDB. Seems like yo have somehow managed to install binary linked libraries for a different platform into the Heroku environment where they are not supported. Developing on Windows perhaps? At a guess I'd say so and you somehow managed to push up your `node_modules` directory to Heroku, where you really should not be doing that. That folder is meant to install and build locally on the deployed environment instead.

Comment: I don't get you. I developed on Mac

Comment: Same deal. Check your `.gitignore` and make sure you are excluding `node_modules` and any other directories or files which are really not part of the source code. ELF refers to binary content which you should not have uploaded to heroku

Comment: Yeah that 's the problem. Thank you so much Neil Lunn. I fixed it. Wish you have a great day!